# How to specify a default value of a function parameter?

Tags: dart

This function should transform each element of the list with the given function transform:

```dart
void _doSomething(List<Something> numbers, [transform(Something element)]) {...}
```

As I don't want to skip this method when the `transform` should not do anything, I wanted to give a default value to the `transform` method like this:

```dart
void _doSomething(List<Something> numbers, 
                  [transform(Something element) = (v) => v]) {...}
```

Unfortunately, the editor tells me

> Expected constant expected

Is there some workaround or simply not possible (or shouldn't be done like this at all)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define the default function as private method :

```dart
_defaultTransform(Something v) => v;
void _doSomething(List<Something> numbers, 
                  [transform(Something element) = _defaultTransform]) {...}
```

Or check argument like this :

```dart
void _doSomething(List<Something> numbers, [transform(Something element)]) {
  if (!?transform) transform = (v) => v;
  ...
}
```

Or like [Ladicek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742081/ladicek) suggests :

```dart
void _doSomething(List<Something> numbers, [transform(Something element)]) {
 transform ??= (v) => v;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is a great argument against the `?check` operator -- you got it wrong in the easiest situation possible. I'd rather advocate using `if (transform == null) transform = (v) => v`.

Comment: Oops, I forgot a `!` ! Thanks !

Answer (score 15):

if you want to initialize a Function parameter that is also a field of your class I suggest:

```
class MyClass{
  Function myFunc;
  MyClass({this.myFunc = _myDefaultFunc}){...}
  static _myDefaultFunc(){...}
}
```

Or more suitable:

```
typedef SpecialFunction = ReturnType Function(
                              FirstParameterType firstParameter, 
                              SecondParameterType secondParameter);

class MyClass{
  SpecialFunction myFunc;
  MyClass({this.myFunc = _myDefaultFunc}){...}
  static ReturnType _myDefaultFunc(FirstParameterType firstParameter, 
                                   SecondParameterType secondParameter){...}
}
```

Comment: For clarity, the function doesn't have to be private. It just needs to be static, so a static member or a global function works.

Answer (score 3):

Write your default parameters inside a square bracket `[]`

```
DummyFunctin(String var1, int Var2,[ String var3 = "hello", double var4 = 3.0, List<int> var5 = [2,4,5,6],] ){
// some calculation
// return something
}
```